# adb install app INSUFFICIENT STORAGE but works from android shell

Tags: android, shell, installation

I am trying to install an app on several devices that installed properly since yesterday but suddenly fails with INSUFFICIENT STORAGE Message. The app installs successfully when installing during debugging or even when installating it from an adb shell internaly as:

```
>adb shell
$ pm install -r  /data/local/tmp/com.pkue.deviceadmin
data/local/tmp/com.pkue.deviceadmin                                     <
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.pkue.deviceadmin
Success
```

But when trying to install from windows command line with:

```
> adb install D:\Projekte\AndroidStudioProjects\MydController\app\MydControllerRelease.apk
5005 KB/s (620253 bytes in 0.121s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/MydControllerRelease.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

The available storage on this particular device is as: (formated for readabilty)

```
adb shell df
Filesystem             Size   Used   Free   Blksize
/dev                   358M  68.0K   358M   4096
/mnt/secure            358M  0.00K   358M   4096
/mnt/asec              358M  0.00K   358M   4096
/mnt/obb               358M  0.00K   358M   4096
/system               1.11G  1.08G  33.0M   4096
/efs                  19.7M  4.13M  15.5M   4096
/cache                 196M  4.11M   192M   4096
/data                 2.18G  1.16G  1.01G   4096
/mnt/shell/emulated   2.16G  1.16G  1017M   4096

/mnt/asec/menion.android.locus.pro-3    29.0M  26.9M  2.05M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.owncloud.android-3        5.01M  3.62M  1.38M   4096
/storage/extSdCard                      29.8G   164M  29.7G   32768
/mnt/secure/asec: Permission denied
/mnt/asec/com.skype.raider-1            41.0M  39.5M  1.45M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.amazon.kindle-1           36.0M  35.0M  1016K   4096
```

I also tried to install the very same app on many different platform and different levels of Android Operating systems including latest level on a Nexus 7. All failed. So I assume that there is somethine generic in the creation of the app itself.
I also added:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

to the manifest, no luck. However if I install it manually from the adp shell, it ends up on the sdcard when the above statement is included.

I am using Android studio 1.1 Beta 4.

I am quite desperate with this issue as it was a maintenance version that ought to fix a number of bugs and the client is waiting...

Any tips?

Comment: Additional information. After wasting more than 6 hours of my time, it turned out that the "debug" version of the app can be installed on any device but the release can not! What the hell has happened. I am about to blame Android Studio for this. I recently installed the latest update (1.1. Beta 4) but of course that migth not be cause but could well be.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be problem with the project settings in Android Studio 1.1. RC1.

In "File/Project Structure/Build Types" the fields '*Application Id Suffix*' and '*Version Name Suffix*' need to be empty in my case. After I cleared those fields, I could install the app again.

For me it is fixed now.